# jQuery timing / cycling delays

Tags: jquery, cycle, html, timing

I need to make some kind of a short "newsflash" on my site... Fading in and out some `s and need them to cycle...

So far I`ve got something like this :

```
$('.text01').hide().fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
$('.text02').hide().delay(4000).fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
$('.text03').hide().delay(8000).fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
$('.text04').hide().delay(12000).fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
```

This however does not cycle and I`m a real newbie so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is another one :)

```
function flow(elem){
    el = $(elem);
    el.fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow', function(){
        nextElem = el.is(':last-child') ? el.siblings(':eq(0)') : el.next();
        flow(nextElem);
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    flow('span:eq(0)')
})
```

[Demo at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/D2VtV/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You should create one div in your page:

```
<div id='newsticker'></div>
```

Then put all your news stories in an array and run this function which calls itself:

```
var newsItems = ['England will win Euro 2012','Pigs will fly by 2030','Third news story','Final news story'];

function displayNews(itemID){
    $('#newsticker').html(newsItems[itemID]);
    $('#newsticker').fadeIn('slow',function(){
        $('#newsticker').delay(4000).fadeOut('slow', function(){
            itemID++;
            if (itemID == newsItems.length){
                itemID = 0;
            }
            displayNews(itemID);            
        });
    });
}

//Start off the news ticker
displayNews(0);
```

See a [Working DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/334Qr/)

Comment: just wonder why did you think he need to switch array texts and not news blocks itself? block may content a lot of stuff. like images, texts, html tags.. etc...

Comment: Because it's a lot neater, easier to modify etc. You could still put HTML in the array and it would work of course.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you have behaves the way you want, you can put them in a function and call that function on a time interval

```
setInterval(your_function_name, time_in_milliseconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this fiddle, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/7gpYB/3/

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you might be looking at something like a content slider.  I'd try something like [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/).  It's a jQuery plugin which you can easily implement and I prefer it because it gives you the ability to skin every aspect of it using CSS, as well as keep your source code to a minimum.  It also supports a lot of callback functions as well as transitions.

Answer (score 0):

I created a function like this one time.  Obviously you would have to wrap your content in a `<li>` for it to work...but maybe it gives you an idea.

```
function liRotator() { 
var liprev = $("ul.rotator li:first-child");
$(liprev).each(function(g) {
  $(this).delay(g*1600).slideUp(function() {
    $(this).appendTo(this.parentNode).slideDown();
  });
});
```

}